# What is $1 and $2 etc in Safari Dev Tools JS Console window?

Tags: javascript, safari

When I run Dev Tools on Safari and use querySelector in console window. I get correct values and then $1 and $2 so on... Can anyone help understand what they mean?

[image]

Comment: It's money...grab it and run!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome:

> ### $0 - $4
>
> Dev Tools remembers the last five DOM elements (or JavaScript heap objects) that you've selected in the tab (or Profiles panel). It makes those objects available as $0, $1, $2, $3, and $4. $0 returns the most recently selected element or JavaScript object, $1 returns the second most recently selected one, and so on.
>
> https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#0-4

Safari:

> ### $1..4
>
> Represents the last, second to last, third to last, and fourth to last selected node in the content browser, respectively.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Console/Console.html