# `navigator.userAgent` on Safari returns UA followed by `= $1` or `= $2`

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, console

Using `navigator.userAgent` in my Safari console, I saw this in the console. I have this string:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.2 Safari/605.1.15" = $1
```

In Chrome I don’t have any similar things. I can obviously see that it isn’t part of the User Agent but sometimes I have also *`= $2`*. What does it mean?

Comment: The _`= $1`_ is just a convenient automatic variable (`$1`) you can use within your console to refer back to the string. It’s not part of the string itself.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+console+what+does+%241+mean) of [What is $1 and $2 etc in Safari Dev Tools JS Console window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34753793/4642212).